# Splitter regex depends on the letter before it

Tags: python, regex

```
I have a couple of pets, e.g., cat, rat, and fish. What about you?
```

I want to split the text above by the period. If I use the regular expression `\.` to split it, I will get `["I have a couple of pets, e","g",", cat, rat, and fish"," What about you?"]`, which is not what I want.

How can I add restrictions to `\.` so that the period preceded by letter `e`, `g` will not be considered splitter?

Comment: Have you tried look around? http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: You could go with Joseph's highly specific answer below, but I suspect the problem you have described is not the problem you are actually trying to solve. Are you trying to split by sentences?

Comment: @Asad Yes that's my ultimate goal. I have to pick up regex techniques along the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!e|g)\.
```

---

I'm not sure if the above works in Python. If it doesn't, try this:

```
(?<!e)(?<!g)\.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to split sentences, you should go by the following regex:

```
\.(?=\s)
```

This one will detect periods followed by a whitespace character.

Maybe you would want to detect also `...` or semicolon ?

Then you should try this one:

```
(\.|\.{3}|;)(?=\s)
```

You could also consider periods ending a line:

```
(\.|\.{3}|;)(?=(\s|$))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try a negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!e|g)\.
```

For your reference:

[Regex Lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)